# Save ggplot2 Image Proportionally to X axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to prepare a few images in ggplot2 where the x-axis varies for each one of my plots. For example, plot 1 has an X-axis that spans 200 units, plot 2 has an X-axis that spans 300 units etc. I would like to save the images so that X axis units for my different images are all proportional and directly comparable to each other. Does anyone know how to do this? When I use ggsave, they all save as the same length, regardless of x-axis units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting the ggsave width as a function of the x-axis total span. For example, the following code will result in a plot with a 10-cm width for the 200 units plot and a 15-cm width for the 300 units plot.

```
width_plot <- 0.05 * (max(data$x) - min(data$x))
ggsave("myplot.jpeg",
       plot = current_plot,
       device = "jpeg",
       width = width_plot,
       height = 8,
       units = "cm",
       dpi = 300)
```